# Referencing UIViewController in NSObject

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to access UIViewController's view in a NSObject class. The NSObject class is suppose to programmatically change UIViewController's user interface. I tried accessing NSViewController's view in NSObject by using self.view but was told that "request for member 'view' in something not a structure or union.

After a few inquiries, I was told that I need to reference viewController in my NSObject class. I am unsure of how to do this and would appreciate any help or point in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to change your tag to "objective-c".
Currently, your tags suggest that this is an objective question about the language "C". ;D

Comment: You can edit your question by clicking the word "edit" at the bottom of your post.

Comment: oo thanks! I just started StackOverflowing 5 minutes ago. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

You should give the NSObject class a property called `myController` or something in its interface declaration, or pass a `ViewController*` to any methods that need to access it.

For the property, you can say:

```
ViewController* myController;
```

in the NSObject sub-class interface declaration, or for the method way, add an argument to your NSObject sub-class' method:

```
- (void) someMethodThatTakesAViewController: (ViewController*) theViewController {
    //Do your stuff here
    theViewController.view = [[UIView alloc] init]; // Or whatever you want to do
}
```

Hope this was what you were looking for.